# Loading Screen in React won't Render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a React component, `PopUp`, that is a popup dialog box displaying information when a user clicks a button. The data that `PopUp` needs to render takes a few seconds to calculate, so in order to keep the website responsive, I want to display a loading message while the data is being calculated, and then render the data once it is available. Here is a simplified version of my component:

```
class PopUp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            data: null
        };
    }

    bigCalculation() {
        const { input } = this.props;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // do calculation
            resolve(result);
        };
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const result = await this.bigCalculation();
        this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            data: result
        });
    }

    render() {
        if(this.state.isLoading) {
            console.log('Loading...');
            return this.renderLoadingScreen();
        } else {
            return this.renderData(this.state.data);
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, when the button is clicked, the `Loading...` message is printed to the console correctly, but the loading screen is not displayed; the website just freezes for a few seconds until the data is calculated, and then renders the data correctly.

However, when I replace the following line in `componentDidMount`:

`const result = await this.bigCalculation();`

with

`await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 5000));`

the component behaves as expected; the loading screen displays for 5 seconds and then switches to the display the data. Why isn't the loading screen rendering correctly?

- Note: `bigCalculation` isn't mutating the state of the component in any way; it simply reads the `input` from the `props` and uses it to produce `result`.

Comment: what if inside your `componentDidMount`, you did `this.bigCalculation().then( setState({...}) )`?  You could remove the `async` and `await` statements.  Would that work?

Comment: I tried that and ended up with the same issue, unfortunately.

Comment: Your code should work on initial mount.  Do you have a loading screen on initial mount?  You mentioned 'when the button is clicked'...what button?  What is the onClick handler for your button?  I feel like we're missing some crucial code here...

Comment: We are missing a lot of the relevant code, I am afraid.

Comment: In your `componentDidMount` function, you should call the setState to loading to true (and keep all the states as is). Then, you should wrap the second setState (where you set the loading to false) in an if statement check if the result is not null... something like `if (result) this.setState({loading: false, data: result})` then I think that'll work. :)

Comment: try setting `isLoading` before the `await this.bigCalculation` . basically, you want to show loading before the big cal IMO.